# Removing ARToolkit nft marker from Android build

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, artoolkit

when i start the sampleNFT -an already made example from ARToolkit- in unity Editor -pressing play button- it worked greatly
BUT when i build my android app it removes my NFT marker which is in this case "gilbratar"
and i made the player setting and Android manifest as good as it supposed to be !
BTW i'm using Unity 5.3.0f4 and ARToolkit 5.3.1

why i have this problem ?!

check this image for more info

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're posting Unity editor logs, but saying you're building to Android. Do you mean you're trying to hit the "Play" button while your build target is set to Android?

If that is the case, I would recommend continuing on the editor set to your desktop platform for debugging purposes, and only switching over to your build target for building.

Also, make sure that the AndroidManifest.xml in your Assets/Plugins/Android folder has it's package name changed from "com.Artoolkit.demo" to whatever you chose as your Bundle Identifier under build settings for Android.

Comment: okay , but ARtoolkit nftsample example doesn't recognize the nft marker
plus the marker counter from inside android app says: marker =0

the problem is -as i think so- is the markers won't load to the apk which make the app doesnt recognize anything

but the log from inside apk says : there is one eligible marker yet on the screen markers = 0

confused as hell